# Routing Error for Rails form using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to post a form to a Rails controller using jQuery and AJAX however I am getting this error:

```
Started GET "/subscription_mails/14/create_recipients?utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=put&authenticity_token=8HtssDY3kxnRlplQbBGlpUspL5ZLq4PqdgiiL5d73yQ%3D&group_ids%5B%5D=3&subscription_mail%5Btarget_users%5D=0&subscription_mail%5Btarget_owners%5D=0&subscription_mail%5Btarget_teachers%5D=0&subscription_mail%5Btarget_teachers%5D=1&subscription_mail%5Btarget_subscribers%5D=0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-29 19:59:47 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/subscription_mails/14/create_recipients"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.1) lib/quiet_assets.rb:20:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  airbrake (3.0.9) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  rack-block (0.1.1) lib/rack/block.rb:47:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error as I have the path defined in my routes. This is my form:

{ :id => "mail-form", :method => :put } do |f| %>

This is the code in my routes file:

```
  resources :subscription_mails do
    put 'create_recipients' => "subscription_mails#create_recipients"
  end
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$('#save-config').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: $('form#mail-form').attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
    data: $('form#mail-form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
  }).success(function(json){
  //act on result.
  });
  return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
```

I'm struggling to figure this out and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your AJAX request is using the GET verb (default), rather than PUT, which is what you defined in the route.  Run `rake -T` to confirm required method and path, then in your AJAX, add `type: 'PUT',` in there somewhere.

Comment: hey thanks for the help. You were right! I didn't define in the .ajax part of the jQuery the type of request.